# Comparing Complex Collections using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

May be my problem is common. I have seen it here [Comparing Two collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407356/comparing-two-collections). But I want to compare two complex collections.

```
public class Project
{
    public Int32 ProjectID { get; set; }
    public String ProjectName { get; set; }
    public String ProjectCode { get; set; }
}
public class Unit
{
    public Int32 UnitID { get; set; }
    public Int32 ProjectID { get; set; }
    public String UnitName { get; set; }
    public String UnitCode { get; set; }
}
```

Here Project and Unit have a Common field called `ProjectID`.And I have a Collection of Project and Unit. Corresponding to each project in the project collection, there is a unit in the unit collection. And some of the units in the unit collection is not belonging to any project in the project collection. I want to Filter out those units. How can I do that using Linq.

Comment: The following references will give you fairly good idea, how to compare complex collections: 1. [Custom Generic Compare For Collection][1]
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality [1]:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16829/Custom-Generic-Compare-For-Collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var result = units.Where(u => projects.All(p => p.ProjectID != u.ProjectID));
```

Comment: Please note some bracket mismatch(es) are there

Comment: I am doing this kind of caparison based a common Datetime field. Its not working as expected. What would be the reason?

Comment: @amesh: Could you post another question mentioned on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
from u in unitCollection
from p in projectCollection
Where p.ProjectID == u.ProjectID
select u
```